# Console app to compare all directory names for similarity

Tags: c#, strings, levenshtein-distance

I just got the urge to write a small console app to compare all directories name for similarity. I have > 3000 directories and over time some of them are really similar, eg. an update: Test Case ver 1 vs. Test Case ver 2.
Well everything is working but it is really slow, it is probably faster for me to sort the directories by name and go through them manually...
The code is 200 lines. I understand that this is a lot more than usual but I could not find something about that in the help section and as mentioned a lot it should be completed so here goes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Similarity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Credit http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
    /// Contains approximate string matching
    /// </summary>
    static class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        #region Properties
        List<string> _blackList = new List<string>();

        public List<string> blackList
        {
            get
            {
                return this._blackList;
            }
        }

        public void AddBlackListEntry(string line)
        {
            blackList.Add(line);
        }
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name).OrderBy(y => new DirectoryInfo(y).Name).ToList();

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"result.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var item in directories)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    sw.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of directories: " + directories.Count());
            }

            if (directories.Count != 0)
            {
                StartSimilarityCheck(directories);    
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No directories");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finish. Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void StartSimilarityCheck(List<string> whiteList)
        {
            int counter = 0; // how many did we check yet?
            foreach (var dirName in whiteList)
            {
                bool insertDirName = true;
                if(!IsBlackList(dirName))
                {
                    // start the next element
                    for (int i = counter +1; i <= whiteList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // end of index reached
                        if(i == whiteList.Count)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        int similiariy = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(dirName, whiteList[i]);

                        // low score means high similarity
                        if(similiariy < 15)
                        {
                            if(insertDirName)
                            {
                                Writer(dirName);
                                insertDirName = false;
                            }
                            Writer(whiteList[i]);
                            Program p = new Program();
                            p.AddBlackListEntry(whiteList[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }

        private static void Clean()
        {
            // yeah hardcoded file names incoming. Better than global variables??
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"similar.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"similar.txt");
                }

                if(File.Exists(@"result.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"result.txt");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void Writer(string s)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"similar.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsBlackList(string name)
        {
            Program p = new Program(); // ieh I don't like this
            foreach (var item in p.blackList)
            {
                if(name == item)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false; // will not be reached
        }
    }
}
```

Except for `StartSimilarityCheck()` everything else can be ignored because my main concern is the performance of said function. Of course I appreciate any reviews. Notice, that I intentionally put all classes and functions inside Program.cs for convenience. If everything works I plan to refactor it but am hang up on the similarity check.

Answer (score 5):

In this code,
it would be better to move the initialization of `int[,] d` further down,
after you check `n` and `m`.

> ```
>         int n = s.Length;
>         int m = t.Length;
>         int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
>
>         // Step 1
>         if (n == 0)
>         {
>             return m;
>         }
>
>         if (m == 0)
>         {
>             return n;
>         }
> ```

---

This loop doesn't loop, so it shouldn't be a loop:

> ```
> foreach (var item in p.blackList)
> {
>     if(name == item)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> return false; // will not be reached
> ```

Also, when you have code like `if (cond) return true; else return false;`,
then you really should write simply `return cond` instead, so in this example `return name == item;`.

Finally, the comment says `// will not be reached`,
but that's not true: it will be reached when `b.blacklist` is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like the general logic is sound. You're looping over items in `whiteList` (which is not really a great name, as it's not names that are guaranteed good, it's names that are being checked) and then comparing them against every other name that's further on in `whiteList`.

However, you're still comparing more than you need to. You don't need the actual Levenshtein distance, you just need to know whether the distance is more than 15 or not. Perhaps you can alter the `LevenshteinDistance.Compute()` method to take the similarity as a parameter, and exit immediately if it knows it's going to be over the threshold.

Secondly, once you've found that a name is too similar, don't keep comparing it! Jump out of the loop early and move along to the next entry. (Don't you want to add both of them to the blacklist, not just the later one?)

Finally, you'll save a lot of time by using a `HashSet<string>` for your blacklist instead of a `List<string>`. It has an extremely fast `.Contains()` method.

Comment: I agree with the whiteList name. I will try to think of a better one.

That is a good idea, I will try to modify it to take a parameter. Thank you.

I am not sure about breaking out of the loop early because what if I have, say 5 directories like this: Dir1, Dir2, Dir3, Dir4,... when compared Dir1 and Dir2 are similar so it would break, missing Dir3 and Dir4. The first one (Dir1) would not be checked again because of the foreach and in the next iteration Dir2 would be on the blacklist and skipped. At least that is what I though but maybe my logic is flawed or I misunderstand something?

Comment: #Takeru I missed that. You're right, you can't jump out early. However, you can make the "blacklist" a `HashSet` that will save you a ton of time. You'd save even more if you just made it a `bool[]` or `List<bool>` with the same size as `whiteList` (or whatever you rename it to).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return false; // will not be reached
> ```

@janos commented,

> Finally, the comment says `// will not be reached`, but that's not true: it will be reached when `b.blacklist` is empty.

In fact, `b.blacklist` will *always* be empty, and that line will *always* run.

This is because a new instance of `Program` is being created:

> ```
> Program p = new Program(); // ieh I don't like this
> foreach (var item in p.blackList)
> ```

`_blackList` is an instance variable, so a new, empty list is created:

> ```
> List<string> _blackList = new List<string>();
> ```

and it's that empty list that is being iterated over.

There is a similar problem with this code:

> ```
> Program p = new Program();
> p.AddBlackListEntry(whiteList[i]);
> ```

A new instance of `Program` is created, with a new, empty `_blackList`. An item is added to that list, and then `p` goes out of scope and is later garbage collected (along with its `_blackList`). This code effectively does nothing.